# List of amino acid frequency of different foods?

Tags: proteins, amino-acids

I'm trying to write a little application calculating the biological value of protein content of different meals using the amino acid frequency of different foods.

The idea is that the user can choose amount and type of different ingredients and finally obtains the biological value index for the meal.

For this calculation I'd need a list of amino acid frequencies of the different foods.

Any idea how I could obtain this?

My first idea was to just use the DNA of the different plants to extrapolate the proteins synthesized and then obtain the amino acid frequency from there but I know that genome and proteome is not correlating.

Any ideas / thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the US FDA's website - it's a vetted website that has this database information - it is listed in this questions as well that appears to be a duplicate... biology.stackexchange.com/q/41844/16299

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable starting place could be the Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations:
http://www.fao.org/docrep/005/AC854T/AC854T03.htm#chI.I

This source looks by no means complete or easy to parse, but some simple web scraping may help you wrangle the data into a database.

Comment: try the US FDA's website - it is listed in this questions as well that appears to be a duplicate... http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/41844/16299